# Paperclip attachments not getting deleted upon destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Attachments saved using Paperclip (v4.2.0) are not being deleted from disk when the model is destroyed, is anybody else experiencing this issue? Everything is working as expected but the files just aren't getting deleted from disk. Any help or ideas would be super appreciated!

Models:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

  has_attached_file :file, { :preserve_files => "false" }
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :subtopic
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:file].blank? }

  validates :topic_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 16 }
  validates :subtitle, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Destroy action in Articles controller:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  begin
    # first delete the attachments from disk
    @article.attachments.each do |a|
      a.file.destroy
    end
    @article.destroy
  rescue
    flash[:danger] = "Unable to delete article"
  else
    flash[:success] = "Article deleted"
  end
  redirect_to admin_articles_url
end
```

Comment: did you try `@article.attachments.destroy`?

Comment: Just now tried @article.attachments.destroy per your suggestion (as well as Gagan's suggestion below), but it's still not working. Records deleted from database as expected, but the saved files are still on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the attachment 'file' attribute to nil before destroying it,  in order to delete the uploaded file from the disk.

So your code should be like this

Destroy action in Articles controller:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  begin
    # first delete the attachments from disk
    @article.attachments.each do |a|
     a.file = nil
     a.save
    end
    @article.destroy
  rescue
    flash[:danger] = "Unable to delete article"
  else
    flash[:success] = "Article deleted"
  end
  redirect_to admin_articles_url
 end
```

Comment: Tried it per your suggestion, but still not working. Actually I had tried a similar thing previously, setting a.file=nil and then a.save, as suggested by Paperclip's own documentation. But it didn't have any effect.

Comment: @NateQ  You are right sorry you need to save after setting it to nil. I have tested it and it works greatly even if I used destroy directly on the object without setting the file attribute to nil. I think the issue comes from  :preserve_files => "false" you should remove it and try again, it should work, the documentation says to use preserve_files and set it to "true" in case you want to keep the files, there is nothing about setting the :preserve_files to false in order to avoid it.

Comment: @NateQ I was wondering if this worked for you, Please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it worked, finally, thank you! Not sure why though, the Paperclip documentation says that :preserve_files is already set to false by default, so it's quite odd that setting it to false explicitly would have any effect. I had already tried it multiple times previously without setting the :preserve_files option and it didn't work at that time. Appears the central issue was I should have been using 'a.file = nil' in the controller instead of 'a.file.destroy'.

Comment: I think the problem was that :preserve_files was set to the string "false", rather than to the boolean false (i.e. without the quotes). All strings evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add preserve_files option to "false" string

`has_attached_file :file, :preserve_files => "false"`

Answer (score 1):

Come up with:

```
  def destroy
    self.transaction do
      self.images.destroy_all
      super
    end
  end
```

`self.images` is collection of records with attachments.
Most important there is `self.transaction do ...` because when for any reason `super` (original `destroy`) failed it wont remove files from hdd. It waits untils COMMIT

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.attachments.destroy
    @article.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admin_articles_url }
    end
end
```

`@article = Article.find(params[:id])` will find the article which you want to delete.
`@article.attachments` will collect all attachments related that particular article

**Note**: you must destroy `@article` after all attachments destroyed. If you write `@article.destroy` before  `@article.attachments.destroy` then it will give an error as @article not found.

As you have mentioned in `Article` model   `has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy`
 then I think no need to write `@article.attachments.destroy` as destroying `@article`  it will delete all attachments related to it.

Comment: Still not working. All records are properly deleted from the database (as before), but the saved files are still on disk.

Comment: local hard drive, specifically:  public/system/files/000/000/0xx/original, where xx is the attachment id

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a **before_destroy** callback

example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_destroy :delete_image

 has_attached_file :image,
              path: "/attachments/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename"

 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: \Aimage\/.*\z/

 private

 def delete_image
   self.image = nil
   self.save
 end
end
```

then any time an instance of the model class is destroyed, then the attachments will be deleted first.